# Are closed questions answerable?

Tags: support, closed-questions

I stumbled in the review queue over this [question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1200090/opera-browser-still-showing-in-mac-launchpad/1200104#1200104)

The question is being closed, because it is a question for mac OS.

If I understood this text

> Closed. This question is off-topic. It is not currently accepting answers.

then no one can write an answer. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically correct yes.

A moderator and/or a group of users with 4 re-open votes could re-open it, someone then could answer it and they could close it again. But that it not something we would do for a question like this. It is indeed off topic

Comment: So what to do now. Converting answer to a comment? Or flag some how? Or ignore?

Comment: Nothing. That answer will soon be deleted. It got 2 delete votes already ;)

Comment: Thank you.  :D :D

Answer (score 3):

If you are wondering how the question came to have an answer, you can see from the question's [timeline](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1200090/timeline) that the answer was posted before the question was closed.

Preventing answers being posted is indeed the primary effect of closing a question. We close questions (except for duplicates) because they are not answerable *within the scope of the site*, that is, they cannot receive an answer that belongs here. The idea is, if answers are posted to questions that are off topic, too broad, unclear, or primarily opinion based, then that increases the quantity of unsuitable content (and also makes it less likely that the question will be deleted or migrated). If duplicate questions receive answers, information that ought to be kept together gets spread out and probably harder to find.